# the function of doGoToPage of a pagedtable doesn't work in processmaker

Tags: jquery, plugins, html-table, bpmn, processmaker

I've made a processmaker plugin and used its CRUD to connect to my db. It used pagedtable to present the data.
Unfortunately, paging won't work and I face "Oops, page not found!"

It seems the event in paging button which has to create a new query and named `doGoToPage` won't work.

[image: paging button]

1. How can I trace its source code?
2. How can I solve my paging problem?